# JQuery SVG not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a circular page with tabs around it and the SVG path are not being appended to the html.

Any help would be grateful.  I have not worked with JS in a long time since I have moved on to Java so my skills are rusty.

```
var tabs = 10;
var radius = 500;
var xcords = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= tabs; i++) {
    xcords[xcords.length] = radius + Math.cos(36 * i + 18) * radius;
}
var ycords = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= tabs; i++) {
    ycords[ycords.length] = radius + Math.sin(36 * i + 18) * radius;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i = 1; i < tabs; i++) {
        $(".svg").prepend("<path class='piece' />");
        $(".piece").attr({
            "d" : "M" + xcords[i] + "," + ycords[i] + "L500,500 L" + xcords[i + 1] + "," + ycords[i + 1] " A500,500 0 0,0 " + xcords[i] + "," + ycords[i] + " Z"
        });
    }
    $(".piece").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.7);
    });
    $(".piece").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 1);
    });
    $(".piece").click(function() {
        $(".center").attr("fill",$(this).attr("fill"));
    });
});
```

I know that the array id not large enough to get xcords[11] but a solution to it would be helpful.

Comment: Do you remember how to open the console now that you've moved on to Java? There's a missing `+` somewhere in there, lets see if you can spot it ?

Comment: What the heck, it's here `ycords[i + 1] " A500,500 0 0,0 "`